# We're a mile ahead of the restaurant already

Tags: word-usage

My mom wants to stop at a restaurant. But we had already passed it. So my dad says:

> We're already a mile **ahead** of the restaurant.

Is the use of "ahead of the restaurant" natural?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not wrong, it's not natural.

Normally, it would be one of the following that would be said:

> We're already a mile **past** the restaurant.
>   The restaurant is already a mile **behind** us.

---

Using [*ahead*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ahead) implies being *in front* of something, either temporally, spatially, or qualitatively.

So, you could say:

> I pulled ahead of you in the race.
>   I will get to the restaurant ahead of you.
>   My education allowed me to get ahead in life.

In your sentence, the only meaning that makes sense is the first one, that of spatial location. If the restaurant is now *behind* you, then it also means that you must be *ahead* of it.

However, it's not normally used in this context. It would be common to say that the restaurant is *just up ahead* as you approach it, but once you've passed it—and if it's not actually a race where two people are in motion—you would refer to *its* physical location behind you, not to your physical location in front of it.

I can't point to a reason why this is the case, other than to say it's just what it is.

Comment: Arguably, ***just*** might be a crucial word here. I can [just about ?!] imagine a context like *I told you when we set off that we should phone the restaurant well before we get there, to make sure they have a selection of vegetarian dishes for me to choose from. But we're already just a mile ahead of the restaurant, and I **still** don't know if they'll actually have anything I can eat!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers To me, *just a mile ahead* would imply that you've already gone past it, so the context wouldn't make sense. Instead, I'd expect to hear *we're only a mile away*. Or are you saying you've sometimes heard you being *ahead* to express not there yet? (If so, that's new to me.) Even *getting ahead of* ***yourself*** means that you've gone too far . . .)

Comment: I think you're being a bit pedantic there. Would you still raise the same objections if my example had been *But the restaurant is already just a mile ahead, and I still don't know...* Come to that, do you have a problem with [*I can't believe fall semester is already just ahead*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+already+just+ahead%22) - which is specifically given as an *example* in a book apparently primarily concerned with "Motion Encoding in Language and Space".

Comment: @FumbleFingers You just changed your example, which might explain our confusion. In your first example you said ***we're*** *already just a mile ahead of* ***the restaurant***. But in your latest example, you said ***the restaurant*** *is already a mile ahead* (of us, I assume). The specific wording aside, the order of the nouns makes a big difference to the semantics. So, I'm not sure what's actually being debated at this point...

Comment: I think the construction *X is [some time duration or distance] ahead of Y* has different *likely* meanings depending on whether X and/or (or *neither*) X and Y are ***moving***. But if the context makes it abundantly clear that Y isn't moving / can't move, *and* that you can't actually go *past* it, I have no problem with usages where ***ahead of*** equates to ***away from***, as in some contexts where you might use [*ahead of the coalface.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22ahead+of+the+coalface%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's assuming that *ahead of* and *behind* do not express anything different, and the order of one thing with respect to another is irrelevant. I think that's an unusual way of looking at things, but I can imagine a context where the only thing that matters is the distance between two things, and anything else is just a matter of perspective. Still, that seems more like an obscure thought problem than a real-word application of language.

Comment: So can it be used? FumbleFingers 12 says that it might just work in specific context. So can it be used? @Jason Bassford

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish Yes, it can be used. As I said, it's not *wrong*. But I still don't believe it's common or natural.

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish: What Jason said. These comments are about a fine point regarding "limits of acceptability". For your purposes, you should just take away the headline message from this answer as regards your example usage: ***it's not natural***. My apologies if my comments might have diluted that message.

Answer (score 2):

> We're already a mile ahead of the restaurant.

implies the restaurant is also **moving along the same path as you are**.  This is likely not the case. :)

Instead

> We're already a mile *past* the restaurant.

You *can* say something like

> We're a mile ahead of the Ice Cream Truck so we'll have to stop and wait for it.